# архитектура service и controller spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, service, controller

Наставьте на путь истинный, что и где должно быть реализовано для взаимодействия контроллера и сервиса. Сигнатуры методов нивелированы!

есть контроллер

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getWords() {
    User user = (User) request.getAttribute("user");
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = wordService.getAll(user, language, limit, offset, draw, searchValue, dir);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

а сервис формирует код ответа тело ответа содержащее данные в формате JSON

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getAll() {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
    jsonResponse.put("status", HttpStatus.OK);
    jsonResponse.put("words", DataToJSON.convertSetWordsToJSON(words, false));
    jsonResponse.put("draw", draw);
    jsonResponse.put("iTotalRecords", count);
    jsonResponse.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", count);

    String resultJson = jsonResponse.toJSONString();
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(resultJson, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Мне кажется что сервис должен просто вернуть набор данных, а контроллер уже формировать ответ, но все же решил лучше спросить.
Подскажите пожалуйста чем должен заниматься сервис а чем контроллер?

Comment: Сервис должен работать с бизнес-логикой, принимать и возвращать бизнесовые модельки. Контроллер - работать с HTTP и конвертировать данные из QueryParams/XML/JSON в бизнесовые модельки и обратно. И вызывать сервис.

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо огромное, оформите пожалуйста как ответ, я отмечу как верный!

Answer (score 0):

Ещё неплохо бы использовать слой Data Access Object - DAO, который бы напрямую работал с POJO - базовыми классами. В DAO Вы проводите манипуляции с данными, бд и тд. В service слое, вызываете свои DAO методы через соответствующие интерфейсы. А уже в контроллерах вызываете объект service и проводите все операции через этот объект.

Comment: А кто вам сказал что он не используется? Да, я его здесь не указал, потому что он и не нужен здесь. В моем случае используется `repository`